# Diagonal of A Matrix From A Text File (No Numpy)

Tags: python, file, matrix, diagonal

I am trying to get the diagonal of a matrix from a text file without using any kind of module. So the text file can have something like:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Here is my code so far:

```
def diagonal(filename): 
    with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
        data=myfile.read().split()
        a=data[0].split()
    a=eval(a[0])
    c=len(a[0])
    d=len(a)
    if c==d:
        diagonal=[]
        c=len(a[0])
        for i in range(d):
            row=[0]*c
            for j in range(c):
                row=a[i][j]
                diagonal.append(row)
        return diagonal
    else:
        return ('Error')
```

This returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

When I want it to output:

```
[[1,0,0],[0,5,0],[0,0,9]]
```

Any ideas on how to make my code work? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please [fix the indentation.](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that the indentation got messed up. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to write down what you want to do in words. You want to construct a list of lists using `a[0][0]`, `a[1][1]`, and `a[2][2]` from the original.  [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) might help.

Comment: Print out variables at strategic locations, like the top/bottom of loops and before/after conditional statements - you will get a *running commentary* of what is happening in your process.

Comment: In our file you have a textual representation of a 2D matrix that uses ONLY `[` `]` `,` and digits, no spaces no tabs nothing else?

Comment: Yes, @gboffi, there are no spaces nor tabs. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, @wwii. Those tips are very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this (example for your given input-list):

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] #Your input-list
new_list = [] #New output-list

for arr, num in zip(l, range(len(l))):
    new_arr = [0 for x in range(len(l))]
    new_arr[num] = arr[num]
    new_list.append(new_arr)
```

This is generic, so you can have a matrix of any length.

Edit: Version with enumerate:

```
for num, arr in enumerate(l):
    new_arr = [0 for x in range(len(l))]
    new_arr[num] = arr[num]
    new_list.append(new_arr)
```

Comment: Why not use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)?

Comment: Thank you so much @Markus! This was really helpful. What does the zip function do exactly?

Comment: @wwii: Edited the enumarte block, forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this simply a nested list comprehension:

```
arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

diag = [[arr[i][i] if i == j else 0 for j in range(len(el))]
       for i, el in enumerate(arr)]
# -> [[1, 0, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 9]]
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mark_M!! Much appreciated!